# I can't figure out how to delete a row in my tasm assembly homework

Tags: tasm

I have a compiled assembly program and I'm asked to modify it by removing the last row seen in the cmd prompt. I'm new at assembly so I can't find a solution.

When you run it 5 rows appear, and I'm trying to delete the row below;

```
Press [q]uit [e]xecute [c]lear:

;Serhad Ali Turhan   040060390
    .8086 
    .MODEL small 
    .STACK 256 
    .DATA 
;~~~~~~ Declarations ~~~~~~~~
CR  equ 13d
LF  equ 10d
cPrompt  DB 'Press [q]uit [e]xecute [c]lear: $' 
cName      DB 'SERHAD ALI TURHAN',CR,LF,'$'
cNum       DB 'Electronical Engineering',CR,LF,'$'
cSch     DB 'ITU Ayazaga Kampusu 34469 Maslak-ISTANBUL',CR,LF,'$'
vDW    DB 0 ;Day of the Week
vMon       DB 0 ;Month
vDM    DB 0 ;Day of the month
cDW0       DB 'SUNDAY$   '  ;All days are 10 bytes
cDW1       DB 'MONDAY$   '
cDW2       DB 'TUESDAY$  '
cDW3       DB 'WEDNESDAY$'
cDW4       DB 'THURSDAY$ '
cDW5       DB 'FRIDAY$   '
cDW6       DB 'SATURDAY$ '


vI2S_I   DW 0       ;2 bytes
vI2S_S   DB ?,?,?,?,'$' ;4 bytes

cExcode  DB 0
;~~~~~~~~ Main Program ~~~~~~~~ 
    .CODE 
MAIN    PROC 
    mov   ax,@data    ; Initialize DS to address 
        mov   ds,ax       ; of data segment 
    call    pClr    
    jmp pExecute
    jmp pMenu       ;

;~~~~~ Menu ~~~~~
pMenu:

    lea     dx,cPrompt  ;
    call    puts        ;
    call    getc        ;AL has user selection  
    push    ax      ;Store it 
    call    pNL     ;
    pop ax      ;
    cmp al,'q'  ;al?=q 
    je  lQuit       ;Quit
    cmp al,'c'  ;al?=c
    je  lClr        ;Clear screen

    cmp al,'e'  ;
    je  pExecute    ;

    jmp pMenu       ;
lClr:
    call    pClr
    jmp pMenu       ;
lQuit:
    call    pQuit

;~~~~~~~~
pExecute:   
    call    pInfo
    call    pClock  
    call    pDate
    call    pNL
    jmp pMenu       ;
pInfo:
    lea dx,cName    ;
    call    puts        ;Display Name
    lea   dx,cNum
    call    puts        ;Display Department
    lea dx,cSch
    call    puts        ;Display School Address
    ret
pClock:
    mov ah,2ch  ;get time
    int 21h
    push    dx
    push    cx  
    mov al,ch       ;ch->hour

    call    pDisp
    mov dl,':'
    call    putc    
    pop ax      ;cl->minute

    call    pDisp
    mov dl,':'
    call    putc    
    pop ax      ;dh->seconds
    mov al,ah
    call    pDisp

    call    pNL
    ret
pDate:
    mov ah,2ah  ;get date
    int     21h 

    mov vDW,al  ;Store day of week
    mov vMon,dh ;Store month
    mov vDM,dl  ;Store day of month
    mov vI2S_I,cx   ;Year will be stored in 
    call    pI2S        ;vI2S_s as ASCII

    mov al,vDM  ;Print day of month
    call    pDisp
    mov dl,'.'
    call    putc

    mov al,vMon ;Print month
    call    pDisp
    mov dl,'.'
    call    putc

    lea dx,vI2S_S   ;Print year
    call    puts
    mov dl,'-'
    call    putc

    call    pDW     ;Print day of week

    ret
pDW:
    mov al,vDW
    mov bl,10       ;All days are 10 bytes
    mul bl
    mov ah,0
    mov bx,ax
    lea dx,cDW0[bx]
    call    puts
    ret
pDisp:
    xor ah,0        ;
    aam
    add ax,3030h    ;
    push    ax
    mov dl,ah       ;
    call    putc
    pop dx
    call    putc
    ret
;vI2S_I=1000*vI2S_S[0]+100*vI2S_S[1]+10*vI2S_S[2]+vI2S_S[3]
pI2S:               ;intToStr
    mov cx,1000     ;
    mov     ax,vI2S_I   ;   
    mov dx,0    
    div cx      ;
    add al,'0'
    mov vI2S_S,al   ;

    mov cx,100  ;
    mov ax,dx
    mov dx,0    
    div cx
    add al,'0'
    mov vI2S_s[1],al

    mov cx,10       ;
    mov ax,dx
    mov dx,0    
    div cx
    add al,'0'
    mov vI2S_s[2],al
    add dl,'0'
    mov vI2S_s[3],dl    ;


    ret

;~~~~~~~~ Screen I/O Functions ~~~~~~~~
getc:
    mov ah,1h       ;read character from keyboard
    int 21h     ;to al
    ret         ;
putc:
    mov ah,2h       ;display character 
    int 21h     ;at dl
    ret         ;
puts:   
    mov ah,9h       ;display string terminated by '$'
    int 21h     ;at the adress dx
    ret         ;
;~~ Clear screen ~~~~
pClr:   
    mov ax,03h  ;
    int 10h     ;
    ret         ;
;~~ New Line ~~~~~~~
pNL:
    mov dl,CR       ;
    call    putc        ;
    mov dl,LF       ;
    call    putc        ;
    ret 
;~~~~~~~~~ Exit ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
;return to DOS 
pQuit:     
    mov     ah,4Ch       ; DOS function: Exit program 
    mov     al,cExcode   ; Return exit code value 
    int     21h          ; Call DOS. Terminate program 
MAIN ENDP 
END     MAIN         ; End of program / entry point
```

Comment: Add the code from Dropbox here (eventually, only the relevant parts).

Comment: ;~~~~~~~~ Main Program ~~~~~~~~ 
    .CODE 
MAIN    PROC 
 mov   ax,@data    ; Initialize DS to address 
     mov   ds,ax       ; of data segment 
 call pClr 
 jmp pExecute
 jmp pMenu  ;

;~~~~~ Menu ~~~~~
pMenu:
 
 lea  dx,cPrompt ;
 call puts  ;
 call getc  ;AL has user selection 
 push ax  ;Store it 
 call pNL  ;
 pop ax  ;
 cmp al,'q' ;al?=q 
 je lQuit  ;Quit
 cmp al,'c' ;al?=c
 je lClr  ;Clear screen

 cmp al,'e' ;
 je pExecute ;
 
 jmp pMenu  ;
lClr:
 call  pClr
 jmp pMenu  ;
lQuit:
 call  pQuit

Comment: it's looking very mixed. because of that i added the dropbox link of the understandable version.

Comment: The dropbox link was 404 here, so I am voting to close this question - it has no answers and seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer some guiding questions:

1. Does the text that you're looking to prevent appear in the code?
2. Is it identified in some way?
3. Does that identifier exist elsewhere in the code?
4. Where does that usage take you?

There are only a handfull of instructions that you care about.  These questions will help you find them, and hopefully understand which one to delete.